# How to override hibernate query for many to many dependancy

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

I have got a Drawer class where attribute File has @ManyToMany dependency as below:

```
@Entity Table(name= "drawer")
public class Drawer {  

     ...

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<File> files;
}
```

File object is defined as below:

```
@Entity(name = "file")
public class File {  

    private String contentType;
    private String name;

    @Column(length = 134217727)
    private byte[] data;

    @Column
    private String size;
}
```

When I query for all Drawer objects it retrieves all files objects too. Some of the files are quite big and slowing the process of retrieving 'all drawers'.

Can I override hibernate query, such that when associated files are retrieved, hibernate retrieves only file name and content type from File table?

Comment: Remove `fetch = FetchType.EAGER`. That precisely does what you want to avoid. Also remove `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` while you're at it: it doesn't make sense on a ManyToXxx association: you don't want all files of a drawer deleted when you deleted a drawer, since they're also referenced by other drawers.

Comment: Removing Fetch Eager will not retrieve any values from File class. I need to retrieve file name and content type. Hence cannot remove FetchType.EAGER. I have changed File class to take out ‘data’ from  File and put it in FileData class. FileData class is lazily initialised in File class. Now all drawers data are retrieved fine (i.e. file data is not included in while retrieving all drawers records). But, for another scenario, I also need to retrieve a drawer with all associated files and its data. How can I can do this?

Comment: JPQL has a `left join fetch` clause. Read about it in the documentation. JPA also has fetch plans. Read about it in the dcumentation.

Comment: Thanks. got it working now